Getting error 'cannot open program database' when building CUDA solution in Visual Studio 2015
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 for compatibility with CUDA Toolkit v8. I've created a new solution/project based on the CUDA template and checked that it builds. At this point, if I close and reopen the solution file and try to rebuild it, I get the following error:
fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'C:\Windows\vc140.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS

It seems that for some reason, Visual Studio is trying to access a non-existent vc140.pdb file inside C:\Windows\. I don't know what may be causing this and I'm at a loss.
Edit: This has probably something to do with the solution being placed in a network shared folder, I can't get Visual Studio to trust that folder, or at least the solution itself.

As you can see in the linked duplicate, this can be caused by many different things, and there are countermeasures you can try to avoid it, depending on your preferences

@talonmies I've already tried all applicable answers to that duplicate question and none worked for me so far.

It may have something to do with untrusted locations but I don't know how to fix that.

That would have been important information to include in your question.

@talonmies I had no idea that could be it at the time of posting, anyway I ended up moving the solution file elsewhere.
